# Factorise and solve equation with unknown denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having trouble with this question

$$3x^4-10x+\frac{8}{x^2}=0$$

The answers page in the book gives this as the answer, but not much in the way of steps.
$$(3x^2-\frac{4}{x})(x^2-\frac{2}{x})=0$$

I am having a lot of trouble factorizing the equation due to the $$\frac{8}{x^2}$$

Comment: Express this as $(3x^6-10x^3+8)/x^2=0$ and you'll probably know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reducing to a common denominator, the equation is equivalent to

$$\frac{3x^6-10x^3+8}{x^2}=0$$ which factors as

$$\frac{(3x^3-4)(x^3-2)}{x^2}=0,$$ easy to solve.

This expression is equivalent to that given in the hint

$$\left(\frac{3x^3-4}x\right)\left(\frac{x^3-2}x\right)=\left(3x^2-\frac4x\right)\left(x^2-\frac2x\right)=0.$$

---

The factorization of the numerator is obtained by setting $t=x^3$, which reduces the equation to a quadratic

$$3t^2-10t+8=0$$ which you should know how to factor/solve.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. I used the 'abc method', using factors -6 and -4. I wouldn't of thought to set use 't' instead of 'x^3'. Either way, I got the answer in the end.

Comment: Also: Why does x=0 not belong in the domain? Is it because 8/0 is undefined, or is there another reason I am ignorant of?

Comment: @Harry: I have reworked my initial answer and dropped the $x\ne0$ condition, letting it implicit as none of these expressions are defined then.

Comment: Not sure I understand how you reduced to a common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x=0$ is obviously not a root, so you can safely multiply by $x^2$ and get a quadratic in $x^3$: $$3x^6-10x^3+8=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$3x^4-10x+8/x^2=0$  ---(1)
multiplying equation (1) by $x^2$
therefore , we get
$3x^6-10x^3+8=0$  ----(2)
let $x^3=t$
therefore equation (2) become
$3t^2-10t+8=0$  ----(3)
on solving equation (3) by synthetic division we get
$(t-2)(3t-4)$   ----(4)
on resubstituting the value of $t$ in equation $4$ we get
$(x^3-2)(3x^3-4)=0$  -----(5)
on diving equation (5) by $x$ we get
$(x^2-2/x)(3x^2-4/x)=0$  ----(6)
thus equation (6) represents the answer